# Discord.py Permission System

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I'm making a public bot in discord.py and I want to check I'm a user is an admin or not via a sqlite3 database. It returns an error shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "", line 143, in permission
    isadmin = conn.cursor().execute('''SELECT rp.GuildID, rp.Permission
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

Here is a portion of my code:

```
    admin = 0
    while admin == 0:
        for y in ctx.message.author.roles:
            print(y)
            isadmin = conn.cursor().execute('''SELECT rp.GuildID, rp.Permission
            FROM rolePermissions AS rp
            WHERE rp.roleID = ? AND rp.GuildID = ? AND rp.Permission = "Admin"''', (y, ctx.message.guild.id))
            print(str(isadmin.fetchall()))
            if str(isadmin.fetchone()) != "None":
                admin = 1
            else:
                admin = 0

    if admin == 1 or ctx.message.author.has_permisions(administrator=True):
        print("User Is Admin")
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=NoPerms)
        return
```

Comment: Why do you want to check roles via `sqlite3`? You can check roles with `discord.py` directly if the bot shares a server with the user and has permissions.

Comment: Because i want them to have admin or whitelist on sqlite so that when the bot become available for the public, it can be set up

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to do this.

discord.py has a built in `@commands.hasrole(role)` feature.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

role = 'rolenamegoeshere'

@bot.command(name='test', help='testing')
@commands.has_role(role)
async def test(ctx):
    #stuff goes here
```

You definitely don't have to use a database or anything, as discord.py has a simple way to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch: `rolePermissions.roleID` is an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY and `y` is a string. Sqlite uses dynamic typing with one exception (from [sqlite FAQ (3)](https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html)):

> Columns of type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY may only hold a 64-bit signed
>   integer. An error will result if you try to put anything other than an
>   integer into an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem this way

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


token = ""
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="|")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        pass
    else:
        manage_messages_permission  = False
        message_len = 0
        while message_len < len(message.author.roles):
            if discord.Permissions(message.author.roles[message_len]._permissions).manage_messages:
                manage_messages_permission = True
                break
            else:
                message_len += 1

        print(manage_messages_permission)

client.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
role = "Admin"
@commands.has_role(role)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest way

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks

bot = commands.Bot('?')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("bot online")
  #This will make bot online

@bot.command()
async def checkadmin(ctx,member: discord.Member=None):
  #command name is checkadmin

  if member is None:
    member = ctx.author
    #This is a command that if member is not mentioned then the member is the person who wrote the message


  if member.guild_permissions.administrator:
    await ctx.send("He is an Admin")
    return
    #This will configure that a member is an admin or not

  if not member.guild_permissions.administrator:
    await ctx.send("He is not an admin")
    return
    #This will configure that the member is not an admin

  
bot.run("BOT_TOKEN_HERE")
#Here paste the token for the bot
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).